# Can someone increase the cost of an Azure Web App with an infinite HTTP loop?

Tags: azure, security, web-applications, finance

I wonder if someone can increase the cost of an Azure web app of an organization, just by creating an infinite HTTP request loop ?

Thanks !

Comment: No, unless the loop involves generating a lot of outbound traffic as you pay for that as well (but that cost is probably neglectable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's depended on the configuration of your App Service Plan. Let's think about some scenarios.

1. No for your App Service Plan without enabled auto scale out feature. Based on this case, the load performance of your service is fixed, so overfulfil the fixed quota of HTTP requests for your app will not increase its cost and the additional requests over fixed load will be blocked by Azure cloud.
2. Yes if you enabled `autoscale` feature as the figure below, more and more HTTP requests sent to your app will activate your App Service Plan to increase the instance number of your app till up to the upper limit of the load capacity of your App Service Plan. Then it will increase your cost to the fixed maximum price.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **No.**

Azure Web App lives *inside* an [**App Service Plan**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans) where you specify the **SKU** and how much **CPU / RAM** you want to have for a **fixed price**.

If someone sends too many requests, he will probably get a temporarily unavailable response code (**503**) if your App Service Plan can't handle more requests.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So would that induce a denial of service ?

Comment: No, there is no ddos protection included so it might happen, that your service is not able to serve any more requests - but your question about the costs remains the same, you wont get charged for that. You could consider using other Azure servicers like Azure DDoS Protection or I belive Application Gatway to get a DDOS protection in place.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with peter pan answer, but problem is if auto scale turned off a hacker can DDoS on your web application, which is also known as HTTP flood and it will make stop serving to your legitimate users. Typically azure infrastructure is secure with sync flood but today malicious actor perform http requests from TOR server or bots (that already installed in many systems). 
For extra security you should go with azure WAF or 3rd party service provider like cloudFlare.

Comment: Yes I was thinking yesterday about CloudFare, good suggestion ! Thanks